# Как добавить в идентификатор переменную?

Tags: javascript

Есть строчка

```
var passed = $('#mydiv' + @(Model.ident)).data('passed-perc');
```

Мне кажется, что идентификатор получается некорректный.

Как сделать так, чтобы идентификатор получился `mydiv1` при условии, что

```
Model.ident = 1
```

Comment: идентификатор получается корректный. почему ты думаешь, что что-от не так?

Comment: @Grundy дело в том, что у меня есть таблица с колонкой "статус", в ячейках которой находится по прогресс-бару. Прогресс прогресс-бара зависит вот как раз от значения `passed`. Кроме того проресс-бар находится в div'е идентификатор которого и является причиной создания темы. Проблема в том, что у меня все значения прогресс-баров записываются в самую первую ячейку, отсюда и предположение, что идентификатор формируется некорректно

Comment: предоставленный код работает именно так как и ожидается. проблема где-то еще